# Polymer Core-overlay doesn't scroll anymore

Tags: android, css, cordova, polymer, android-5.0-lollipop

I have been working on a mobile app using Polymer.  I just recently ran into a problem where Polymer's core-overlay box does not let me scroll down, and it just leaves content cutoff. It's basically an info box that comes up when you tap it with your finger.

Everything was working perfectly last Tuesday, until the big Android 5.0 update hit the very next day on my phone. That's when things started to become buggy. My co-worker's phone still has the Android 4.4 version, and it scrolls down and up just fine. I'm wondering if anyone else has/is running into this too or have a solution to this. Also, I am using a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Cordova.

Here is the CSS and some of the HTML for the core-overlay element that I mention:

```
<core-overlay id="infoOverlay" class="dialog" layered backdrop transition="core-transition-center" core-overlay-toggle>
    <style no-shim>
        .dialog {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #999;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            text-transform: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: black;
            padding:20px 20px;
            outline: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
        #infoOverlay {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            /*text-align: center;*/
            width: 80%;
            height: 70%;
        }
        #settingsTitle {
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.5em;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .settingsText {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
        .settingsTextLast {
            padding-top: 10px;
        }
    </style> 
    <div id="dummydiv">imagine enough divs</div>
</core-overlay>
```

Any help, information, or anything would be greatly appreciated! I think I provided enough information, but I will provide more upon request.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work if you set `overflow` in your `.dialog` to `auto` or `scroll`.